# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(3^x+7^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} ?$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(3^x+7^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

I did in this way:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(3^x+7^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

$=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}[(1+\frac{1}{3^x}+1-\frac{1}{7^x})(3^x\cdot7^x)]^{\frac{1}{x}}$

$=21\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{3^x}+1-\frac{1}{7^x})^{\frac{1}{x}}$

$=21\cdot1=21$

But the limit given in the solution is $7.$

I'm not getting where is wrong!!

Comment: How did you get the first equality? Check it carefully.

Comment: $$\left(1+\frac{1}{3^x}+1-\frac{1}{7^x}\right)(3^x\cdot7^x)\ne 3^x+7^x$$

Comment: yeah I got that!! Silly mistake!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint

$$b^x<a^x+b^x\le2b^x$$ for $b\ge a>0$

Answer (score 1):

Applying $e^{\ln(x)}=x$ and other properties of logarithms, you can see that

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
\lim_{x\to\infty}(3^x+7^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} & = \lim_{x\to\infty}\large{e^{\ln{(3^x+7^x)^{\frac{1}{x}} }}}\\
 & = \lim_{x\to\infty}\large{e^{\frac{\ln{(3^x+7^x)}}{x}}}\\
& =\large{e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\ln{(3^x+7^x)}}{x}}}}\\
& =\large{e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\ln{(7^x)}+\ln{\big((\frac{3}{7}})^x+1\big)}{x}}}}\\
& =\large{e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\ln{(7^x)}}{x}}}}\\
& =\large{e^{\lim_{x\to\infty}{\ln{(7)}}}}\\
& =7
\end{split}
\end{equation}